# Integrate $∫(\frac x a )\exp(-\frac x a )dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to calculate

$$\int \tfrac{x}{a} e^{-x/a}dx.$$

I have tried many times and I can't find an antiderivative. How can I find it?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: yes but i dont know how to resolve that

Comment: If you are familiar with the formula $\int uv' \operatorname{dx}=uv-\int u'v\operatorname{dx}$ you can make the substitution $u=\frac xa, v'=e^{-\frac xa}$ and go from there.

Comment: Do you need answers to all six integrals?

Comment: yes i hope to give me a clear answer

Answer (score 2):

An idea: first, substitution

$$t:=\frac xa\implies dx=a\,dt\implies\text{ our integral is}\;\;\int t\,e^{-t}a\,dt=a\int t\,e^{-t}dt\;\;(**)$$

Now, by parts:

$$\begin{cases}&u=t,&u'=1\\{}\\
&v'=e^{-t},&v=-e^{-t}\end{cases}\;\;\implies\;(**)=-te^{-t}+\int e^{-t}dt$$

and now just solve the very last integral and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Use u-substitution. Let $u = -\frac xa$, then $du = -\frac{dx}{a}$, and the integral becomes

$$a\int ue^{u}du  = a[(u-1)e^u] = a\left(- \frac{x}{a} -1\right)e^{-x/a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For any $f(x)$,
$(f(x)e^x)'
= f'(x)e^x+f(x)e^x
$.

Therefore
$\int f(x)e^x dx
=f(x)e^x-\int f'(x)e^x dx
$.

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial,
this reduces
$\int f(x)e^x dx$
to $\int f'(x) e^x dx$.

In this case,
$f(x) = x$,
so that
$f'(x) = 1$.

Therefore
$\int xe^x
=x e^x -\int e^x dx
$.

You should be able to take it from here.

By induction,
this shows that,
if $f(x)$
is a polynomial of degree $d$,
then

$\int f(x)e^x dx
=e^x\sum_{k=0}^d (-1)^kf^{(k)}(x) 
$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one has noted that this is essentially the incomplete gamma function. I understand that the OA is interested in how to integrate, but one should always seek to generalize as well. I mean, supposing tomorrow's question is how to integrate

$$∫\left(\frac {x}{a}\right)^{\nu-1} e^{-x/a}dx$$

In the present case $\nu=2$, and the solution is given exactly as

$$-a\left(\frac {x}{a}+1\right)e^{-x/a}$$

More generally, if $\nu$ is an integer, the solution is given by

$$\Gamma(n,x)=∫_x^{\infty}t^{n-1} e^{-t}dt=(n-1)!\text{e}_{n-1}(x)e^{-x}$$

where $\text{e}_n(x)$ is the *exponential polynomial*, defined as

$$\text{e}_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{x^j}{j!}$$